# How would I clip a continuous action in an actor-critic agent?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

Let's say we have a bot that has some money and some shares. The input is a list of prices for the last 30 days. It doesn't use an RNN and the prices are entered all at the same time. The output is a continuous action where a positive number is to buy and a negative number is to sell the amount of the stock. How can I restrict the action space so that it is clipped between how many shares it has(the lower bound) and how much money it has(the upper bound)?

Should I have it clipped or just penalize an illegal action? Which option would create the best results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can penalise illegal actions, but in my experience it hasn't shown to have a good effect on the AI (one more thing to worry about). Just clip the output so that if it tries to use more money that it has available it spends all its money. If it tries to sell more of a stock than it has, it sells all of it's stock. The network will learn what happens when it tries to use more resources than it has quite quickly, so it wont cause any degrade in performance.

Comment: If I clip it and it returns high rewards in the future, would it keep increasing the number, higher and higher? Wouldn't this cause numerical stability?

Comment: It depends on your architecture. While in a simple policy-gradient model it would certainly be a problem, actor-critic solves that. Because the reward would be the same no matter how far above the clipping threshold it outputs, once the critic learns that it will stop increasing the output.

Answer (score -1):

The AI cannot sell a share amount it doesn't have or buy a share which is worth more than the money it has, so you should not allow this kind of transaction at all. However, if your AI looks at the trends and prefers shares which are expected to be more valuable in the near future, then there is a good chance that the total amount of property will be higher the next day. Let's say share1 had a starting value of s1 and an ending value of e1 and share2 had a starting value of s2 and an ending value of e2, then in the case when

**e1 / s1 > e2 / s2**

it is better to give share1 a higher priority. If any si / ei is smaller than 1, then the AI should not invest into it.

Also, you should value stability, if a share's value has increased continously in the last few days, then it has an increasing trend. If a share's initial value is smaller than the ending value, but in the last few days its value decreased, then it might be a decreasing trend and the share should not be preferable. Such rules need to be implemented and when they are conflicting, the AI must be able to intelligently choose its priorities.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote? If so, I would be glad to know it, so I can improve the answer.